# How to fill username password in phraseexpress (Text expander)

Tags: productivity, textexpander

I used to fill usernames/password combinations in Texter (Another Text expander) like:

pragmaticprogrammer{TAB}Hello1

How to do the same in phraseexpress ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to waste US 140 for such simple task:

1. In Phrase Express, just use {#TAB} and {#ENTER}.
2. You should not use the spammer's product "PhraseExpander" to store passwords as it is unsafe. However, Phrase Express offers password protected files so you you can safely store your confidential phrases and passwords: http://manual.phraseexpress.com#pwd